# Contar Registros de 2 tablas con mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla cliente y una tabla ruta. La tabla clientes tiene un campo que se llama documento, requiero contar los clientes que tienen documento y los que no lo tienen.

**Mis tablas**

tabla cliente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tabla ruta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté:

```
SELECT e.name as ruta, COUNT(c.idcli) AS totalClient FROM tablaRuta e INNER JOIN tablacliente c ON c.idruta = e.idruta GROUP BY e.name
```

pero esta consulta solo me devuelve el total de clientes por ruta.

**ACTUALIZACION**

Probe esta consulta pero me devuelve 0 en ambos

```
SELECT ntbl_routes.name as routeName,(select count(1) from ntbl_client where ntbl_client.document!= null) conDocumento,(select count(1) from ntbl_client where ntbl_client.document= null) SinDocumento from ntbl_routes #INNER JOIN ntbl_routes on ntbl_routes.idroute = ntbl_client.idroute;
```

**ACTUALIZACION 2 (A RESPUESTA DE ***David JP***)**

Algo asi quiero

+-------------+-------------------+--------+

| RutaNAME   | Con Documento |  SD         |

+-------------+-------------------+------- +

|   Ruta 1   |   120   |    12           |

|---------------------------------------------

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: añade más detalle de tus tablas, campos y columnas porque mostrándolo así solo estás haciendo que adivinemos para solucionar el problema.

Comment: para qué se necesita la tabla ruta entonces?

Comment: listo, actualizado

Comment: la tabla ruta es para que aparezca un contador ejemplo 

Ruta 1 5 cliente con documento 8 sin documentos 

como ejemplo

Comment: ¿`tablacliente`  y `ntbl_client ` son distintas o son la misma tabla?

Comment: son la mismas tablas

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes si una ruta tiene documento o no? ¿Con el campo `idoffice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora entiendo lo que planteas:

```
SELECT * FROM ruta
  JOIN (
    SELECT idroute,
      SUM(IF(LENGTH(document)>0,1,0)) ConDocumento,
      SUM(IF(LENGTH(document)>0,0,1)) SinDocumento
      FROM cliente
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 USING(idroute);
```

¿Puede ser esto lo que buscas?

Comment: Jesus!!!!!! me has salvado la vida, mucha pero muchas gracias, es esto exactamente lo que andaba buscando

Comment: si deseara agregar la clausula where como seria

Comment: Pues al final, justo antes del `;`, o entre `FROM cliente` y `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que, en la tabla `cliente` guardas el `idroute` cuando efectivamente hay fichero y, mientras tanto, dejas un `NULL`. Lo que podría ser mucho suponer...

Entonces haría:

```
SELECT document,
  COUNT(idroute) ConDocumento,
  COUNT(*)-COUNT(idroute) SinDocumento
  FROM clientes
  GROUP BY 1;
```

También valdría, si lo que guardas en `idroute` es un `0`:

```
SELECT document,
  SUM(IF(idroute=0,0,1)) ConDocumento,
  SUM(IF(idroute=0,1,0)) SinDocumento
  FROM clientes
  GROUP BY 1;
```

De otra forma, tendrías que explicar un poco más la semántica de tus tablas, indicando la función de cada una y lo que guardas en cada campo. Sobre todo `idoffice`.

Espero haber acertado. Déjame cualquier duda e indicación en los comentarios.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, por tu comentario, he probado la consulta y aunque no me resolvio este inconveniente, si me funciono para otro que tenia en fila, te agradezco el apoyo

Comment: en teoria  cada ruta tiene clientes , y necesito contar los clientes que tienen documento y los que no lo tienen, por eso el campo ruta y con respecto idoffice es el identificador de su ultima oficina visitada